# Why is a Cross-Domain HttpOnly Cookie received by the browser but not saved?

Tags: node.js, cookies, cross-domain, setcookie, httpcookie

*Hi everybody*,

after hours of googling and trying every approach I could find I haven't found a solution to my problem.

I am trying to save a JWT Token in an HttpOnly cookie but although my server sends the cookie correctly it doesn't get set in the browser.

I have CORS enabled on the server-side, the cookie being sent is not `Secure` has the `Path '/'` and has set `SameSite=none`. The domain is set to `localhost` because that's where my frontend is running and `HttpOnly=true`.

The cookie is received correctly and is visible in Chrome as `token=eyJ...hcP; Max-Age=31104000; Domain=localhost; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 05 Aug 2021 12:22:35 GMT; HttpOnly, SameSite=None`

I'm guessing the problem is that the frontend is running on localhost:3000 and the backend on localhost:4000.

I would appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm guessing the problem is that the frontend is running on localhost:3000 and the backend on localhost:4000.

This is the answer. `localhost:4000` and `localhost:3000` are not the same domain when regarding cookies.

The most common solution is to use [`webpack-dev-server`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/). This dev-server will be responsible for two things.

1. serve static files (your single page application).
2. **Proxy** API request to your API server.

So you will need to implement this as a part of your frontend development environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I thought of that solution too. Is there actually no way to share a cookie between two domains? I thought it would be possible but couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: In the past, it was possible to share cookies between domains but nowadays most browsers have disabled this ability due to security concerns.

Comment: Okay, that's why there are many explanations on the internet showing how to make a cookie domain-indedepent but none worked. They all were deprecated. Thanks for your help!